Metric entropy of an ellipsoid
Let $B^d_2$ denote the unit ball of $\ell_2^d$ and let $T$ be an invertible linear map.
Consider the function
$$
H(T) := \log M(TB_2^d, B_2^d), 
$$
which is the packing entropy for $TB_2^d$ by $B_2^d$.
Question:
Is a general, explicit characterization of $H(T)$ available?
For instance, the Sudakov minoration yields
$$
H(T) \lesssim \bigg(\mathbb{E}_g \sup_{x \in B_2^d} \langle g, Tx\rangle\bigg)^2 \asymp \mathrm{tr}(T^\ast T).
$$
(Here $g$ is distributed standard Gaussian in $\mathbf{R}^d$, and $\lesssim$ indicates inequality up to absolute constants and $\asymp$ denotes equality up to constants, independent of everything.)
Of course, this cannot be sharp as $T = I_d$ already shows.

Do theorems 4 and 5 of Allard and Bolcskei answer your question?

Not really, these estimates are also not sharp in general.
